# Is the floating point implementation of exp() function equivalent to a truncated Taylor series expansion?

Tags: c++, cmath, exp, taylor-series

Is the floating point implementation of exp() function in cmath equivalent to a truncated Taylor series expansion of a very high order? One possible source of the error we should keep in mind is the finiteness of the number of bits to represent the answer

Comment: That's extremely unlikely. There are much better "practical" algorithms around for hardware arithmetic units (and also for software implementations) that converge much faster. They're usually quite obscure and very nifty and not terribly widely known amongst pure mathematicians.

Comment: Although Taylor series work in theory, series expansions can be subject to significant precision loss

Answer (score 5):

> Is the floating point implementation of exp() function in cmath equivalent to a truncated Taylor series expansion of a very high order?

Equivalent to? Yes. That's because any decent implementation of `exp()` has an error of half an ULP (unit of least precision) or so. Ignoring problems with finite precision arithmetic, one can always construct a truncated Taylor series that does the same.

However, no decent implementation of `exp()` will use a Taylor expansion. That would be very very slow, and wouldn't achieve the desired accuracy. It would be a downright stupid implementation. Much better is to use the fact that there is a strong relation between 2<sup>x</sup> and e<sup>x</sup> and the fact that 2<sup>x</sup> is fairly easy to compute given the almost universal power of 2 representation of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Just an example how you could calculate exp (x):

If x is quite large then the result is +inf. If x is quite small then the result is 0.

Let k = round (x / ln 2). Then exp (x) = 2^k * exp (x - k ln 2). 2^k is very easy to calculate. A small problem is to calculate x - k ln 2 without any rounding error. That's quite easy: Let L1 = ln 2 rounded to say 35 bits, and L2 = ln 2 - L1. k is a smallish integer, so k * L1 has no rounding error, nor has x - k * L1; then we subtract k * L2 which is small and therefore has little rounding error.

To do this quicker (without a division), we calculate k = round (x * (1 / ln 2)). And we check whether x is close to zero, so the whole calculation isn't needed. Anyway, we now calculate exp (x) where the result is between sqrt (1/2) and sqrt (2).

You could calculate exp (x) using a Taylor polynomial. Instead you would probably use a Chebychev polynomial minimising the cutoff error with a much lower degree. With some care you can find a polynomial with a cutoff error substantially less than the lowest bit of the result.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the compiler, C runtime and the processor. However, whoever computes the exponent is unlikely to use the Taylor expansion since better methods exist.

As per glibc, it may use its own implementation which says this in the comment (from sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_exp.c):

```
/* An ultimate exp routine. Given an IEEE double machine number x          */
/* it computes the correctly rounded (to nearest) value of e^x             */
```

Or it may use hardware supported processor instructions for floating point computations, as with x86 FPU. In both cases you are likely to get a correctly rounded value with full precision.

Answer (score 0):

That's dependent of which C library implementation you're using. In the overy popular glibc, it isn't.

Comment: I am using intel compiler. What algorithm is used in glibc to compute exp() ?

Comment: @Tarek I don't know exactly what it is, something involving magic constants, but why not see it yourself?

Comment: @Tarek: I don't know either, but a much better method than Taylor expansion would be to use [Hermite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation) on a finite interval using precomputed constants and exploit the exponential format of the floating point in order to reduce the problem to that finite interval.